# BigQuery DeDuplication on two columns as unique key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We use BigQuery religiously and have two tables that essentially were updated in parallel by different process. The problem I have we don't have a unique identifier for tables and the goal is to combine the two tables with zero duplication if possible.. The unique identifier is two columns combined.

I've tried various MySQL-based queries, but none seem to work in BigQuery. So I am posting here for some assistance.  :)

Step 1. Copy the "clean" table into a new merged table.

Step 2. Query the "dirty" (old) table and insert any missing entries.

**Query Attempt 1:**

```
SELECT
  COUNT(c.*)
FROM
  [flash-student-96619:device_data.device_datav3_20160530] AS old
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    [flash-student-96619:device_data_v7_merged.20160530] AS new
  WHERE
    new.dsn = old.dsn
    AND new.timestamp = old.timestamp 
)
```

***Error: error at: 6.1 - 10.65. Only one query can be executed at a time.***

**Query Attempt 2:**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [flash-student-96619:device_data.device_datav3_20160530]
WHERE
  (dsn, timestamp) NOT IN (
  SELECT
    dsn,
    timestamp
  FROM
    [flash-student-96619:device_data_v7_merged.20160530] 
  )
```

***Error: Encountered " "," ", "" at line 6, column 7. Was expecting: ")" ...***

Honestly, if I could do this in one query I would be happy. I need to fetch from two tables, and make a new one with unique data.

Any assistance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like below should work

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dsn, timestamp) AS dup
  FROM
    [flash-student-96619:device_data.device_datav3_20160530],
    [flash-student-96619:device_data_v7_merged.20160530] 
) 
WHERE dup = 1
```

I recommend using explicit list of fields instead of * in outer SELECT so you can omit dup from actual output

Comment: What about two tables though. I don't want to de-dupe against the one table itself, but another table. I guess I can write to a table, then re-write to a table...

Comment: this was direction to follow :o)  - anyway added second table - idea is to dedup combined data (from both tables) and write it into final clean table. hope this is what you meant to achieve

Comment: You're on fire my friend.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I wanted to point out that your original query works with minor modifications using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options"). I just had to change `new` to something else, since that's a reserved keyword. For example, this query is valid:

```
WITH OldData AS (
  SELECT
    x AS dsn,
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4]) AS x),
NewData AS (
  SELECT
    x AS dsn,
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST([5, 2, 1, 6]) AS x)
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM OldData oldData
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM NewData newData
  WHERE
    newData.dsn = oldData.dsn
    AND newData.timestamp = oldData.timestamp
);
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   2 |
+-----+
```

In regard to your second attempt, you can do:

```
WITH OldData AS (
  SELECT
    x AS dsn,
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4]) AS x),
NewData AS (
  SELECT
    x AS dsn,
    TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST([5, 2, 1, 6]) AS x)
SELECT
  *
FROM OldData
WHERE
  STRUCT(dsn, timestamp) NOT IN (
  SELECT AS STRUCT
    dsn,
    timestamp
  FROM NewData);
+-----+---------------------+
| dsn |      timestamp      |
+-----+---------------------+
|   3 | 2016-07-21 11:54:08 |
|   4 | 2016-07-21 10:54:08 |
+-----+---------------------+
```